# 'Relish on' or 'Relish upon'

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Does this sentence sound correct?

> Here's a bowl of dessert to relish upon.

Or it should be-

> Here's a bowl of dessert to relish on.

Comment: You don't want *any* preposition after ***relish*** in such contexts. But note that few native speakers would use ***relish*** in this way. We normally only use the verb *figuratively* today, to refer to some appealing future possibility *(I would relish the opportunity to meet him).* It's very unusual to use it literally, as in *I'm relishing this tasty meal*, and even more weird to use it in an "imperative" like *Please relish this tasty meal which I have served to you*.

Comment: Unless you mean "to put relish (=a condiment) upon something"

Comment: Never really went for the idea of Branston pickle on my blancmange…

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - my parents were very fond of a product called 'Gentleman's Relish' which is still available. It's very pungent and salty, made with anchovies, and good on toast. When I tell younger people about it, some giggle at the name (think 'Chef's Special Sauce').

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - You can still get it in Waitrose, right next to the poacher's relish [salmon-based] & mushroom ketchup. I've never tried it, I don't like fish in general.  Marmite on carrot cake would at least be two things I like …separately ;)

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Relish requires no preposition, you don't relish "on" or "upon" anything, you just relish it.

> Here's a bowl of desert to relish.

Comment: Except no native speaker would ever say that.

Comment: Here's x which I relish. A bowl of desert is weird.